# time possessive

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives, time-words

> 1. It will take 5 days to manufacture them
> 2. It took us half an hour to wait

If I want to change the sentences above to noun phrases, time's possessive form, can I write them as below, thanks in advance.

> 1. 5 days' production
> 2. Half an hour's waiting

Comment: I am not sure but is this you are looking for? `the production for 5 days`, or `5 days for production`;
`the waiting for half an hour`, or `half an hour for waiting`;

Comment: I want to know if the possessive form can be used for the same meaning as I write above,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples are correct.

Depending on the context, you might change the phrasing.

"Five days' production" would often be phrased "Five days' production time" and "Half-hour's waiting" would often be phrased "a half-hour's wait." But again, this will depend on the rest of the sentence.